# Is removing a MessageBodyMember in a MessageContract considered a breaking change?

Tags: c#, wcf, messagecontract

Consider the following ServiceContract-Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    void MyMethod(MyClass obj);
}
```

With MyClass beeing:

```
[MessageContract]
public MyClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 0)]
    public int A { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public int B { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

`MyClass` is now changed to look like the following:

```
[MessageContract]
public MyClass
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 0)]
    public int A { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 2)]
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

Would a client consuming this WCF-Service need to make additional changes to work with the new service definition?

Additionaly, what would happen if I were to additionally change `C` to have the new `Order = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client updates the WSDL File, it gets a syntax error in the code of the client, when the client calls the method.

The order element set on which position in the communication the bodymember sending to the server/client. You can see it into the svc log. Example.:

```
<ns2: myClass xmlns:ns2="yourNamespace">
<A xmlns=""></A>
<B xmlns=""></B>
<C xmlns=""></C>
</ns2:myClass>
```

After changed the ordner element:

```
<ns2: myClass xmlns:ns2="yourNamespace">
<C xmlns=""></C>
<A xmlns=""></A>
<B xmlns=""></B>
</ns2: myClass >
```

I have tried the example for you. I have used a WCF C# Web service and a C# client with a standard protocol: BasicHttpBinding. And I use the WCF Test client. In this combination I got no error in the client, provided that the client makes no WSDL update. In this case, you can change the order element without errors. But this is not a correct implementation; therefore you can’t assume that everything is working. For other clients see the result might be different. For example, a Java client is much more restrictive.

Comment: Thank you! Since the Class is only used to send data from client to server I take it that with your explanation the client can still use the service even if no wsdl update was made?

Comment: If you send data from client to server, with the object “MyClient”, you have to fill the Object into the client. Isn’t the client set the MessageBodyMember “B”?

Comment: Of course the client will still fill "B" and pass it to the server, the client hasn't updated the wsdl. The question is: Will the server be able to handle this and take on the request?

Comment: What happend when you have an object inside an object? Can you use the Order attribute for other the inside properties?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @naro's answer:

It is **not** a breaking change for the following frameworks:

- .NET (C#, 4.5)
- Java 8

I did not test anything else as it doesn't matter for our scenario.

This means every client still works (without regenerating the client) even after updating the web service definition.